# No effect from calling jQuery method from its function object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

**TL;DR** Can anyone tell me how to correctly call a jQuery function from its object?

**Background**

I'm trying use jQuery methods to build an HTML object from a description given by a JSON object. Part of that is trying to apply a set of attributes defined by a JSON object to an element - very similar to the existing [jQuery attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). The difference is that it aims to apply certain 'special' attributes (e.g. css and innerHTML) more intelligently through function calls.

e.g. a css attribute will applied through a call to jQuery.css()

**The Problem**

Everything is working except the calls to jquery functions for special attributes:

```
   var specialAttrFunctions = {
    'log': console.log,  // works
    'css': $(this).css,  // fails without error
    'html': $(this).html,  // fails without error
    'innerHTML': $(this).html  // fails without error
  };
  specialAttrFunctions['log']('log me'); // works
  specialAttrFunctions['html']('innerHtml sample'); // does not work
```

**Things I've tried without success**

```
($.fn.html).call(this, 'innerHTML');
($.html).call(this, 'innerHTML');
(this.html)('innerHTML');
($(this).html)('innerHTML');
```

**The whole thing**

I've attached the entire file below for if that turns out to be relevant.

```js
keyIntersection = function(object1, object2) {
  var sharedKeys = [];
  for (var property in object1) {
    if (object1.hasOwnProperty(property) && object2.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      sharedKeys.push(property);
    }
  }
  return sharedKeys;
};

$.fn.extend({
  setAttrs: function(attributesObject) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var attributesCopy = $.extend(true, {}, attributesObject);
      var specialAttrFunctions = {
        'log': console.log,  // works
        'css': $(this).css,  // fails without error
        'html': $(this).html,  // fails without error
        'innerHTML': $(this).html  // fails without error
      };
      keyIntersection(specialAttrFunctions, attributesCopy).forEach(function(key) {
        specialAttrFunctions[key](attributesCopy[key]);
        delete attributesCopy[key];
      });
      $(this).attr(attributesCopy);
    });
  }
});

var createDomObjectFromJson = function(domObjectJson, $parentElement) {
  var $element = $(document.createElement(domObjectJson.type));
  $element.setAttrs(domObjectJson.attributes || {});
  (domObjectJson.children || []).forEach(function(child) {
    $element.append(createDomObjectFromJson(child));
  });
  if ($parentElement) {
    $parentElement.append($element);
  }
  return $element;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var testData = {
    'type': 'div',
    'attributes': {
      'log': 'The log function call works correctly',
      'data-test': 'test1',
      'css': {
        'width': '640px',
        'height': '480px',
        'background-color': 'lightblue',
        'border': '1px solid black'
      }
    },
    'children': [{
      'type': 'p',
      'attributes': {
        'data': 'test2',
        'innerHTML': 'Hello Paragraph!',
        'title': 'paragraph title'
      }
    }]
  };
  createDomObjectFromJson(testData, $('body'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No flocking clue. It feels like the context of `this` in the `$(this).html` is...not what you want, but I don't know what you need to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has to do with the `this` context when the functions are invoked. When you call `specialAttrFunctions[key](attributesCopy[key]);` the `this` context in the invoked function is the `specialAttrFunctions` object instead of the jQuery-wrapped element object that it must be in order for the jQuery prototype methods to work.

What we need to do is, when constructing our functions map, `specialAttrFunctions`, to be sure to bind the jQuery prototype methods to the correct context. For efficiency, I would first cache the jQuery-wrapped element in a variable and then [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) that variable to the appropriate functions. The end result would look like the following:

```
var $el = $(this);
var specialAttrFunctions = {
    'log': console.log,
    'css': $.fn.css.bind($el),
    'html': $.fn.html.bind($el),
    'innerHTML': $.fn.html.bind($el)
};
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/h2oo9bao/) for your reference.